# Doxygen - Document a struct variable but not the struct

Tags: c, doxygen

Let's say I have this struct type:

```
typedef struct Hidden Hidden;
struct Hidden
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
};
```

and then I have a global variable

```
Hidden visible;
```

`Hidden` should never be used and `visible` should be the only declaration of type `Hidden`. I don't want to generate documentation for `Hidden` as I don't want it to be used, but instead generate documentation for `visible` with all the information about it and about its fields.

The closest thing I've found is that when you document a `struct` with no tag like:

```
struct
{
    int foo; ///< Number of particals in the universe.
    int bar; ///< Number of socks in the drawer.
} Baz; ///< Nameless struct variable.
```

Doxygen will generate

```
struct {
   int foo
       Number of particals in the universe. 
   int bar
       Number of socks in the drawer. 
} Baz
  Nameless struct variable.
```

This is the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve, but I can't use nameless structs.

Is such thing possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to do it. Using proprocessor predefines as @RBE suggested lets you create code only for doxygen which won't compile anyway. So just do this (and make `DOXYGEN` a predefined macro):

```
typedef struct Hidden Hidden;

#ifdef DOXYGEN

struct
{
    int foo; ///< Number of particals in the universe.
    int bar; ///< Number of socks in the drawer.
} visible; ///< Nameless struct variable!

#endif

struct Hidden
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

Hidden visible;
```

It's hacky, but it works.

Comment: Just a note here - it is strongly recommended not to leave undocumented parts of your API especially if the contents of the undocumented functions/enums/structs/etc. are actually documented.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you want is to use a macro definition to switch between the code you will compile, and the code you will run doxygen on:

```
#define DOXYGEN

#ifdef DOXYGEN
/**
 *  @brief Describe your visible structure here.
 */
typedef struct VISIBLE
{
    int foo; //< Number of particles in the universe.
    int bar; //< Number of socks in the drawer.
} VISIBLE;
#else
typedef struct HIDDEN
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
} HIDDEN;

HIDDEN visible;
#endif
```

Simply comment or uncomment the `DOXYGEN` definition to switch from one to the other.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I don't want to just change the name of the structure from HIDDEN to VISIBLE. I want to generate documentation just to a single struct variable instead of documentation for the struct type itself.